# trying to read out xml but getting the html

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

if you check this link: http://armory.wow-europe.com/guild-info.xml?r=Aegwynn&n=Quite+Tight

its a usuall html in the visual way.. but if you right click and open the source code there is a xml i need for my solution.

Im using the XmlReader .. but he reads out the html.. how can i solve this?

this is my code part:

```
        string url = "http://armory.wow-europe.com/guild-info.xml?r=" + realm + "&n=" + editedGuildName;

        // XML Resolver
        XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
        resolver = null;

        // XML reader
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            guildDataList.Add(reader.ReadString());
        }
```

my list is getting filled with the html visual of the page

Edit:

the first few parts of the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/_layout/guild/roster.xsl"?><page globalSearch="1" lang="de_de" requestUrl="/guild-info.xml">
  <tabInfo subTab="guildRoster" tab="guild" tabGroup="guild" tabUrl="r=Aegwynn&amp;gn=quite+tight"/>
  <guildInfo>
    <guildHeader battleGroup="Blutdurst" count="76" faction="1" name="quite tight" nameUrl="quite+tight" realm="Aegwynn" realmUrl="Aegwynn" url="r=Aegwynn&amp;gn=quite+tight">
      <emblem emblemBackground="39" emblemBorderColor="14" emblemBorderStyle="5" emblemIconColor="14" emblemIconStyle="145"/>
    </guildHeader>
```

I saw some guys working with the xml i need to work with by using PHP with the following part of code:

```
$url    = "http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-sheet.xml?r=".urlencode($realm)."&n=".urlencode($char);
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4");
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 10);
$contextOptions = array("http" => array ("header" => "Cookie: cookieLangId=de_de\r\n"));




$context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);
@$file = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context);

if( empty($file)) {
    return false;
    exit;
}

#   neues DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->loadXML($file);
```

it seems to work fine for them.. im not good in php .. so i dont really know what they are doing different.

Comment: Sorry but looking at the source of the page you gave, this is standard html we are looking at.

Comment: I didn't see any xml when I view that page source. Using wget doesn't return any xml, either.

Comment: very strange.. i'm opening it with firefox 3.6.13 and it shows me true xml... see my edit

Comment: Darkdog, your link currently shows a error "These aren't the Armory pages you're looking for" (atleast for me) thus I see the error page instead of the information of your guild.

Comment: yes Theun thats true... thats because world of warcraft switched to a new armory .. but the xml system stays at the old one. it only matters for the visual way.

Comment: Found your XML file when looking at source code in IE.  Chrome shows the html page.

Comment: The XML is there, this is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works - for some reason the request only retrieves the HTML if you do not set the client's user agent appropriately (just a sample identification below, could be any browser). The server must do some sort of check evaluating the User-agent header - after setting it, it delivers the XML:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("User-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)");
string resultXML = wc.DownloadString("http://armory.wow-europe.com/guild-info.xml?r=Aegwynn&n=Quite+Tight");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(resultXML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Greeting darkdog,

I noticed that when I download the file "http://armory.wow-europe.com/guild-info.xml?r=Aegwynn&n=Quite+Tight" (using a small a href html file) I do get the xml file.
However I believe that when you access the site from the C# side you get the HTML code.

Perhaps find a way to first download, temporarly save it on your disk, access it's data and after you are done delete it. (Like BrokenGlass has given a example for)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to the question and what I see when I load the page, I assume you are logged in when you see the xml (perhaps automatically by Firefox). Therefore, your code is probably getting the same error page (html) that we are all seeing, which is why you are having a problem.

If this is the case, you will have to log in programmatically in order to get around this issue.

Comment: i edited my post once again by showing some successfull ways php coders got with the xml

Comment: I think it's not this.. but the program does find the html page instead of the xml. 
I believe you should have the location of the xml which i'm trying to find now.

Comment: They are making a request to a different url... character-sheet.xml on an `eu` site.

Comment: the url doesnt matter .. because character-sheet.xml and guild-info.xml is quite the same.. just containing different information